# Read CSV file with geotools library Java

Tags: geometry, csv, java, geotools

I found in the geotools documentation this code for reading CSV file and extract geometry
seems not working for me even with the data test they have in the web site.

feature.getDefaultGeometryProperty() returns null

```
Map<String, Serializable> params = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
params.put("file", "locations.csv");
params.put(CSVDataStoreFactory.STRATEGYP.key, CSVDataStoreFactory.SPECIFC_STRATEGY);
params.put(CSVDataStoreFactory.LATFIELDP.key, "LAT");
params.put(CSVDataStoreFactory.LnGFIELDP.key, "LON");
DataStore store = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);

String typeName = dataStore.getTypeNames()[0];

FeatureSource<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> source =
        dataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);
Filter filter = Filter.INCLUDE; // ECQL.toFilter("BBOX(THE_GEOM, 10,20,30,40)")

FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> collection = source.getFeatures(filter);
try (FeatureIterator<SimpleFeature> features = collection.features()) {
    while (features.hasNext()) {
        SimpleFeature feature = features.next();
        System.out.print(feature.getID());
        System.out.print(": ");
        System.out.println(feature.getDefaultGeometryProperty().getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: your datastore is called `store` but you refer to `dataStore` in the rest of the method. Works for me with 27.0

Comment: and `CSVDataStoreFactory.FILE_PARAM.key` would be better than `"file"`

Comment: i've corrected the store and dataStore, still found issue in my csv file 
It must be comma separated value or i can specify it to be semicolon ? 
Thank you for

Comment: by default it's a `,` - but you can use `params.put(CSVDataStoreFactory.SEPERATORCHAR.key, ";");` to change it